# forms not working in microsoft edge browser

Tags: php, forms, browser, microsoft-edge

I am working on a project and working forms in the project don't seem to do what I expect when I visit my site with edge.

I am running the project on a local webserver and access it with it's local ip.

With edge I can register, login, but when I have logged in I can't use any other forms I have on my website.

When I try to submit a form after logging in edge pops up a window telling me the browser has to do some tasks and has lost the location of the page.

The forms work just fine in Firefox and Chrome (I also heard Safari works fine but I don't have that browser myself.)

I will post a tiny portion of the HTML:

```
<form action="map.php" method="POST" name="player_move">
    <button class="button" type="submit" name="east" style="color: white;">E</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, the form code would be helpful, otherwise we cannot see how the code is sent. POST/GET/Javascript/...?

Comment: It's always POSTed on my website I don't use GET anywhere

Comment: Well it's rather large code snippet to begin with. I will post a tiny portion of it. `code` <form action="map.php" method="POST" name="player_move"><button class="button" type="submit" name="east" style="color: white;">E</button></form>

Comment: Obviously E is not the only direction. there are multiple buttons in that form with all directions (NW, N, NE, E, W, SW, S, SE)

Comment: Just out of interest could you swap the button for an <input type='submit'>

Comment: There was an issue a while back with edge submitting forms via <button> it's plausible your edge is either out of date or a new version has reintroduced this issue.

Comment: this could be true, I don't use edge in a normal situation, it could be outdated. I have to see how I can update that browser (normal updates on pc are always happening isn't edge included in that process?) I don't have these buttons on register and login forms so it's worth investigating.

Comment: Just checked it and it says this: Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0
HTML 13.10586

Comment: I have to investigate swapping <button> to <input type> for effects on edge (and other browsers) if it works I'll come back to report. For now I'll notify my edge users to rather not use it.

Comment: Personally I use Linux so I have no experience in edge what's so ever sorry. If an update isn't the issue, do you have any javascript on the problem pages? Once in Safari I had a bug which caused the page to reload every few seconds due to a missed ; on one line yet it still functioned in all other browsers. This may be something afflicting you?

Comment: there is some javascript involved, but it is only used with register forms. other forms are in pure php. as is the login script. changing from <button> to <input type> might take me some time to test out. I'm pretty sure I didn't miss a beat (;) with my semicolons.